# Messages get lost when one node subscribes to many topics

Tags: ros-humble

I have a node A that needs to subscribe to 3 different topics. I now noticed that it doesnt receive all of the messages on one topic. I tested if the publisher of that topic works correctly by creating a node B with a single subscriber assigned to that topic, and it receives all messages. So it seems like the problem lies on the subscriber side of that node A.

I tried different QoS settings and queue lengths, but it didn't help.

Does someone know what the problem might be?

Comment: Without more information, it is honestly really hard to pinpoint the issue here. Your use case is very simple which leads me to think that there is some kind of dumb error.

Can you provide code that shows the publisher, subscriber in question?
You can also list topics, listen to the publisher from command line or fire up rqt to see if there is a connection between the nodes via this topic. Leave all the QoS settings in defaults.